# Adding foreign key that references a column which is not Primary or Unique key

Tags: mysql, database-design

I got into trouble when I want to limit values of Table A's column to be taken only from a set of optional values in Table B's relevant column.

Problem is table B's relevant column isn't a foreign key.
And if I will do that I guess that the correct state where I can have the same values multiple time for different columns values will be impossible- and this is not the behavior I look for.

So what can be done?

Answer (score 5):

So `table2.columnB` must contain a value from `table1.columnA` *but* there could be duplicate values in `table1.columnA` so you can't declare it unique? Apparently InnoDB does allow this, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362163/mysql-foreign-key-by-non-unique-key-how-is-that-possible for discussion, but standard SQL (and therefore most databases) explicitly does not (it renders some operations like `ON {DELETE|UPDATE} CASCADE` potentially inconsistent) so I would avoid the option.

If there is a fixed set of valid values you could keep them in their own table with a unique/primary key defined upon the column, then both `table2.columnB` and  `table1.columnA` can be foreign keys referencing the new table.column.

A less clean option would be to write triggers to maintain the foreign key manually, as mentioned in http://cvuorinen.net/2013/05/validating-data-with-triggers-in-mysql/ amongst other places you should find easily via your preferred search engine. You need to be careful to consider all possibilities logically and efficiently, so I would recommend the "new entity type and foreign key" method instead - that will be less bug prone, probably more efficient, and might better model your data anyway (perhaps the properties represented by those columns *should* be entities in their own right).

Comment: Yes, exactly. Referencing a not PRIMARY or UNIQUE column is a bad idea. Even if MySQL allows it, it should never be trusted.